# Problem with Folding Library in Tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to run through a trail but can't seem to get it to work.  Code goes as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}

 %optional libraries
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations,arrows,automata,positioning}
 \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{folding}
 \usepackage[grapics,tightpage,active]{preview}
 \setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2pt}
 \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\tikzfoldingdodecahedron
[folding line length=10mm,
face 1 = {\node {1};},
face 2 = {\node {2};},  
face 3 = {\node {3};},
face 4 = {\node {4};},
face 5 = {\node {5};},
face 6 = {\node {6};},
face 7 = {\node {7};},
face 8 = {\node {8};},
face 9 = {\node {9};},
face 10 = {\node {10};},
face 11 = {\node {11};},
face 12 = {\node {12};},

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problems:

- Twice `\begin{tikzpicture}`
- `\tikzfoldingdodecahedron`:

  - options not closed: `]`
  - not ended with `;`

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

%optional libraries
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,arrows,automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}
\usepackage[grapics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
\tikzfoldingdodecahedron
[folding line length=10mm,
face 1 = {\node {1};},
face 2 = {\node {2};},  
face 3 = {\node {3};},
face 4 = {\node {4};},
face 5 = {\node {5};},
face 6 = {\node {6};},
face 7 = {\node {7};},
face 8 = {\node {8};},
face 9 = {\node {9};},
face 10 = {\node {10};},
face 11 = {\node {11};},
face 12 = {\node {12};}
];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```